# Excel VBA - clear blank not empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have cells that are blank but not empty. 
Is there a way to clear that content from them?

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: I have an excel file where for some reason all numbers are stored as text. And where a number is not present there's a blank cell. I convert it all to numbers. And then I need to go each empty cell and press delete because it was not actually empty (if i did counta() it'd count them as not empty)

Comment: If they are not empty, what do they contain? Spaces?

Comment: No, I believe it's some kind of an object. It's similar if you for example have A1="". It's a blank cell, not empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each c In Selection
    If IsNumeric(c) Then
        c.Value = 1 * c.Value
    Else
        c.Value = Delete
    End If
Next c
```

I used this code.
This converted numbers stored as texts to numbers.
And blank not empty cells to empty cells.
And it worked.
It's a bit slow for big ranges, but it works fine.